# Falling back to alternative value if include_bytes!(…) target is missing

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

My package has a binary target that uses [`include_bytes!(…)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_bytes.html) to bundle a copy of some precomputed values into the compiled binary. This is an optimization, but isn't strictly necessary: the program is capable of calculating these values at run time if the bundled data slice [`.is_empty()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.is_empty).

The program needs to be able to build without this data. However, `include_bytes!("data/computed.bin")` causes a build error if the target file does not exist.

```
error: couldn't read src/data/computed.bin: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

Currently, I have a Bash build script that uses `touch data/computed.bin` to ensure the file exists before building. However, I don't want to depend on platform-specific solutions like Bash; I want to be able to build this project on any supported platform using `cargo build`.

How can my Rust program `include_bytes!(…)` or `include_str!(…)` from a file if it exits, but gracefully fall back to an alternative value or behaviour if the file doesn't exist, while only using the standard Cargo build tools?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use a [build script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) to ensure that the included file exists before out package tries to include it. However, build scripts can only write to the current build's unique output directory, so we can't just create the missing input files in the source directory directly.

> error: failed to verify package tarball
>
> Caused by:
>     Source directory was modified by `build.rs` during `cargo publish`. Build scripts should not modify anything outside of `OUT_DIR`.

Instead, our build script can create the file-to-include in the build directory, copying the source data if it exists, and we can update our package code to include this data from the build directory instead of from the source directory. The build path will be available in the `OUT_DIR` environment variable during the build, so we can access it from `std::env::var("OUT_DIR")` in our build script and from `env!("OUT_DIR")` in the rest of our package.

```rust
//! build.rs

use std::{fs, io};

fn main() {
    let out_dir = std::env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap();

    fs::create_dir_all(&format!("{}/src/data", out_dir))
        .expect("unable to create data directory");

    let path = format!("src/data/computed.bin", name);
    let out_path = format!("{}/{}", out_dir, path);

    let mut out_file = fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .append(true)
        .create(true)
        .open(&out_path)
        .expect("unable to open/create data file");

    if let Ok(mut source_file) = fs::File::open(&path) {
        io::copy(&mut source_file, &mut out_file).expect("failed to copy data after opening");
    }
}
```

```rust
//! src/foo.rs

fn precomputed_data() -> Option<&'static [u8]> {
    let data = include_bytes!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/src/data/computed.bin")).as_ref();
    if !data.is_empty() {
        Some(data)
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but this might affect Rust's ability to detect when the source file is changed and needs to be rebuilt.

Answer (score 1):

While using a build script (like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56016804/4674154)) would work, I am not a fan of that solution:

- **The build script copies the file** – depending on the file size, that might be prohibitively expensive. Though one could probably solve this problem using hardlinks instead.
- **An empty file might be perfectly fine data** – the solution would misdetect an empty file as missing. However, depending on the use case, an empty file might actually be perfectly valid.
- **It is very verbose** – this turns a simple `include_bytes!` into a build script of approximately 20 lines and additionally a few more lines when including to handle the `data.is_empty()` case.
- **It is hard to grasp what is happening here for a casual reader** – why is this script including something from `$OUT_DIR`? It would probably take a moment for the reader to get the idea a build script might be involved here.
- **It does not scale well** – most of those problems would get even worse if there were multiple files that needed to be included optionally.

I therefore decided to write the procedural macro crate [include_optional](https://docs.rs/crate/include_optional/1.0.1) to solve this problem (currently only works on nightly Rust because it depends on some unstable features).

With this, the solution to this problem is a one liner:

```rust
use include_optional::include_bytes_optional;

fn precomputed_data() -> Option<&'static [u8]> {
    include_bytes_optional!("./computed.bin")
}
```

There are also macros wrapping `include_str!` and `include!`.